# Samsung phone not getting detected by adt for a specific Android project

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, eclipse-adt

I have used my Samsung phone for running an android app(very basic app) once. I was trying to work on another app, but now, when I turn on the usb debugging in my phone and try running the new one, my phone doesn't show up in the CHOOSE A RUNNING ANDROID DEVICE list. I tried to run the previous app again, just to see if it works now, and surprisingly, it does ! I don't remember doing anything else other than turning on the usb debugging thing in my phone.
Any help would be appreciated :)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have enabled usb debugging from your phone .....if yes follow this ..
First Install This Software on your `pc` then install `apk` on your phone

get it from here 
http://www.mobogenie.com/product/mobogenie-pc.html

Comment: I have installed the software you've asked me to do on my pc. I have the apk file in my pc and am trying to copy it on my phone to install it using App Installer application, but the apk file is not getting copied.
Also wanted to ask you that why did it work for my previous app without any of these being done.

Comment: it is enabled in my phone

Comment: restart your phone then try again :)

Comment: u can a new project then try to run on your phone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable ADB through command line tool .
For reference you can follow this link :[See the link here](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/)

And if there is any further issues please comment below.

Comment: I am working on linux. In the link you've mentioned, it says in android sdk manager google usb driver has to be installed, but for me it shows that it is not compatible with linux. Is it important that google usb driver has to be installed? @sushritha

Answer (score 0):

You need to install device driver for your Samsung devices After that you can restart your Eclipse & attach phone with usb.Now you can see the devices in devices list.

Comment: I have installed device driver and restarted eclipse. Still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Connect phone by USB cable to your computer.Remember to set

`android:debuggable="true"`

in your AndroidManifest file
You'll also need "`unknown sources`" ticked under

```
Settings -> Application.
```

Try this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

[Connecting Your Own Device On Eclipse safely to run Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306087/connecting-your-own-device-on-eclipse-safely-to-run-application?lq=1)

Comment: I have done this and it worked for my first app. I haven't changed anything since then. Now when i try to run another app(new one), it is not getting detected :( I think I am missing something which is silly. Any suggestions?

Comment: which IDE you are using?..also make your projects min sdk version same as that of your phone

Comment: I'm using eclipse IDE

Comment: i hope you have done all the rest configurations like enabling developers option,USB debugging and kies installation etc

Comment: your question seems to be too abstract. you can repeat the procedure needed for debugging application on device again. follow this link http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51276/samsung-galaxy-s4-usb-not-recognized-by-windows-7